# Wordpress If else statement to hide or show a div based on population a field

Tags: php

First time poster. PHP idiot.

I need to (re)write code that will display a div if a field is entered but to hide it if it's empty. The field is populated using a custom field in the backend of Wordpress.

I wrote this code many years ago and it used to work but no longer does. My skill level is 0. This is it:

```
<?php
$video = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'video_file_name', true);
if ($video == '')
{ ?>
<div class="hide">
<!-- hide video -->
</div>

<?php } else { ?>
<div class="show">

This a javascript block that shows a video player.

<script src="this_code_is_hidden.js"> </script>
<div id="mediaspace">text will be replaced</div> 
<script type="text/javascript">   
jwplayer('mediaspace').setup({
'file': 'http://video.xxxxx.com.au/<?php the_field('video_file_name'); ?>',
"advertising": 
     {
    'client': "vast",
    'tag': google ad invocation code
  },
 'title': '<?php the_title(); ?>',
        'ga': {
        'idstring': '<?php the_title(); ?>',
        'label': '<?php the_title(); ?>'
    },
'image': '<?php the_field('poster_frame'); ?>', 
"sharing": {
    "link": "http://www.xxxxx.com.au"
},
'controlbar': 'bottom', 
'stretching': 'fill',     
'width': '100%', 
'aspectratio': '16:9',
'height': '332'
}); 
</script>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

I've hidden some bits for security.

The theory is when ('video_file_name') is populated it will show the javascript block which will display a video.

I use CSS classes to either hide or show.

If anyone can shed some light I would be most appreciative. I've spent hours searching and trying but not clever enough to make it work.

I don't know if you can 'echo' a whole code block.

Thank you.

Comment: Try changing this `if ($video == '')` to `if( empty( $video ) )`.

Comment: In what way is it not working?

Comment: Hi Tony, I'll give it a shot.

Comment: Hi Vancoder, it's not hiding the div when the text field is empty.

Comment: Hi Tony @tony, I've tried your suggestion and unfortunately it hasn't worked. Have I set up my variable incorrectly. `<?php
$video = get_post_meta($post->id, 'video_file_name', true);
if ( empty( $video ) )
{ ?>
<div style="display:none;">
<!-- hide video -->
</div> 

<?php } `ATM moment when the text field 'video_file_name' is entered, it's hiding the div - the opposite I was hoping for!

Comment: Add a `var_dump()` after you get the post meta:
`<?php $video = get_post_meta( $post->id, 'video_file_name', true ); var_dump( $video ); if( empty( $video ) ) : ?> <div style="display:none;"><!-- hide video --></div><?php endif;`
If it's empty, then your `display:none` should activate, but if there's something there, it shouldn't.

Comment: Hi Tony, I appreciate your help! When I drop the new code in i get this [link](https://imgur.com/Q7CXkNj) - do I need an 'else' rather than 'endif'? I'm not questioning your code, but trying to understand. This is what it looks like when I don't have a filename [link](https://imgur.com/Q7CXkNj) using `if (!empty( $video ) )` code. If I use `if ($video == '')` , I get the complete opposite - when I don't have a file name it hides the div, but **if** i have a file name, it still hides the div. I'm slowly losing my mind.